# Изменение значения глобальной переменной с помощью функции

Tags: c, функции

Как изменить значение глобальных переменных с помощью функции?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

void swap(int a, int b) {
    int sw;
    sw = a;
    a = b;
    b = sw;
}

int main() {
    int a[10];
    int i, j; 

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for (j = i+1; j < 10; j++)
            if (a[i] < a[j])
                 swap(a[i], a[j]);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вам бы эту самую глобальную переменную объявить бы... А то вопрос очень странно звучит. А проблема-то у Вас на самом деле не с глобальной переменной, а с передачей параметров в функцию `swap()`. Подсказываю - внимательно посмотрите на Ваш вызов функции `scanf()` , которая _изменяет_ второй аргумент и подумайте, с чего бы оно было так сделано... Если не додумаетесь, тогда можно учебник полистать - фактически во всех учебниках по Си есть пример функции `swap()`.

Comment: В приведеном коде нет глобальных переменных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю, вопрос в том, чтобы изменить значение входных параметров функции `swap`. Ваш код работает неверно по одной простой причине — в C все аргументы передаются *по значению*, поэтому чтобы изменить какие-то переменные во внешнем коде, мы должны передать в функцию *адреса* этих переменных. И затем по этим адресам записать некоторые значения. В этом нам помогут *указатели*.

Указатель — это переменная, содержащая адрес другой переменной. Взгляните на следующий пример:

```
int n = 10;
int *a = &n;

printf("%d", *a); // Выведет 10.
```

Здесь `n` — это переменная типа `int` со значением 10, а переменная `a` — указатель, который *указывает* на `n` и содержит адрес переменной `n`.

> Одноместная операция * называется операцией ссылки по указателю (indirection) или разыменования (dereferencing). Применяя ее указателю мы можем получить объект, на который он указывает.

Форма такого объявления переменных (`int *a`) задумывалась авторами языка как мнемоническая: это объявление сообщает, что выражение `*a` имеет тип `int`.

---

Теперь мы можем написать рабочую версию функции:

```
void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int const tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}
```

Для того чтобы *получить* адрес какой-либо переменной, нужно применить оператор взятия адреса (`&`):

```
swap(&a[i], &a[j]);
```

---

Кстати, в книге The C Programming Language (K & R), в главе «*5.2 Указатели и аргументы функции*» рассматривается как раз ваш случай с функцией `swap`.